# How to solve issues regarding deprecated APIs?

Tags: flutter, dart

Everytime I run `flutter build apk`, the following notes are exposed. How can I get rid of them?

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: .pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_messaging-14.6.2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/messaging/FlutterFirebaseMessagingPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: .pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/geolocator_android-4.1.8/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/geolocator/location/FusedLocationClient.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```